# Why is Sprite a null?

Tags: c#, image, user-interface, unity-game-engine, sprite

So I have classes: `Item` , `Weapon` that inherits from `Item` , `ItemFactory` and some `InventoryController`.
Code:

```
public class Item : MonoBehaviour {
      protected float scale = 1;
      public float Scale { get
        {
          return scale;
        }
      }
      protected int id;
      protected int rarity;
      static protected Sprite sprite;

      public Item()
      {
        id = -1;
      }

      public Item(int id)
      {
        this.id = id;
      }

      public bool IsEmpty()
      {
        if(this.id==-1) return true;
        return false;
      }

      public Sprite getSprite()
      {
        return sprite;
      }

    }

public class Weapon : Item{

  public Weapon()
  {
    scale = 0.25f;
    id = 1;
  }     
  void Awake()
  {
    sprite = GetComponent<Image>().sprite;
  }

}
```

`InventoryController` calls to `ItemFactory` to make `Item` for it and then I use this code to set `Item` into inventory:

```
public void AddItem(Item item)
  {
    for(int i=0; i<slotAmount; i++)
    {
      if (items[i].IsEmpty())
      {
        items[i] = item;
        GameObject itemObj = Instantiate(inventoryItem); // Its empty item prefab
        itemObj.transform.SetParent(slots[i].transform);
        itemObj.transform.position = slots[i].transform.position;
        itemObj.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = item.getSprite(); // Its null
        itemObj.transform.localScale = new Vector3(item.Scale, item.Scale);
        return;
      }
    }
  }
```

Even thought scale comes right the sprite I get is `null`. Tried to Debug it and `item.getType()` returns `"Weapon"` if `ItemFactory` returns new `Weapon`. So the Question is why sprite I set to this item is null?
I call the `ItemFactory()` like this:

```
ItemFactory itemFactory = new ItemFactory();
AddItem(itemFactory.makeItem(1)); // makeItem(int type) returns the Item of type Weapon if type == 1
```

You have asked for  `ItemFactory` code so here it is:

```
  public class ItemFactory : Item {

  public ItemFactory() { }

  public Item makeItem(int type)
  {    
    if(type == 1)
    {
      return new Weapon();
    }
    else
    {
      return new Armor();
    }
  }
}
```

Also to explain the   `Weapon` prefab here is a screenshot of it:
[Weapon Prefab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsEUh.png) weapons_3 is image I want to use.

Comment: You default scale in your weapons constructor. Sprite is never set. Do you set it in your factory?  What's your factory code look like?

Comment: We would need to see the constructor code for ItemFactory

Comment: Weapon holds the sprite as its UI->Image and is a prefab so as you see on Awake it gets it. I Debuged to see if sprite in weapon acctualy exists. Also if I hardcode the AddItem to get only Weapon instead of all items the sprite acctualy shows up.

Comment: Also, why is sprite static? Is that intended? That will give all your items the same sprite.

Comment: You never call awake though.

Comment: Yes it will give my ALL weapons the same sprite. It is intended as I'm creating just a demo for educational purpose.

Comment: Awake is called in Unity automatically whenever game starts before anything else.

Comment: Oh. I probably should have looked at your tags. I don't know unity. :p

Comment: No problem. I'm just explaining it .

Answer (score 0):

I made it work though it's not elegant. I changed the ItemFactory class so it holds the item it created so I can get the Sprite from ItemFactory.

```
public class ItemFactory : Item {

  private Item item;

  public ItemFactory() { }

  public Item makeItem(int type)
  {

    if(type == 1)
    {
      item = new Weapon();
      sprite = Weapon.getSprite();
    }
    else
    {
      item = new Armor();
      sprite = Armor.getSprite();
    }
    return item;
  }

  public Sprite getItemSprite()
  {
    return sprite;
  }
}
```